# Accessing null-termination character in std::string (string subscript out of range)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider the following very simple text example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string x("ugabuga");
    int i=0;
    while (x[i]) {
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%d\n",i); //should print 7
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the program to iterate over all characters of the string, then reach the null-terminating character breaking the loop and reach the program end correctly.
However, when I tried compiling it in debug mode under Visual Studio 2010 I am reaching an exception "string subscript out of range".
When compiling in release mode this program passes, but my bigger project depending on this behaviour crashes - perhaps because of this issue.

However, when I checked the specification of `std::string::operator[]` at [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/), the end-character string is handled explicitly:

> If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to a null character ('\0').

I would like to ask here:

- Is my interpretation of specification of `std::string` correct? Or am I missing something?
- If the problem lies on VS side of implementation, how can I easily fix this - hopefully without calling `length()` each time I use the `operator[]`? e.g. will using `c_str()[i]` will be safe?
- If the problem lies on VS side of implementation - do you know if it is fixed in VS 2012 or pehaps will be fixed in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the things that changed between C++03 and C++11.

It seems it is undefined behaviour in C++03:

> **21.3.4 basic_string element access [lib.string.access]**
>
> `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`
>
> `reference operator[](size_type pos);`
>
> 1 Returns: If `pos < size()`, returns `data()[pos]`. Otherwise, if `pos == size()`, the `const version returns charT()`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

while in C++11, it is OK.

> **21.4.5 basic_string element access [string.access]**
>
> `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`
>
> `reference operator[](size_type pos);`
>
> 1 Requires: pos <= size().
>
> 2 Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT();` the referenced value shall not be modified.

Comment: So the solution for the OP would be to iterate using a constant reference: `const std::string &cx = x; while (cx[i]) ...`.

Comment: @rodrigo That would make it defined behaviour. I don't know what problem OP is trying to solve, but I suspect the `while` loop in question is just a means to understand something. Otherwise one would just use `x.size()`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Do you know how far VS is in implementation of these? To answer your question: I am implementing a simple parser within the loop. Recognizing letters, numbers, whitespace and the end-of-string.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Sorry, I am not sure about which version of VS you would need to get C++11 strings. But you can loop over the indices `[0, x.size())`.

Comment: VS C++ 2010 and up seem to have a std::string that provides access to the terminating null character per the C++11 standard.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: The test case in the question proves otherwise for VS C++ 2010.

Comment: @CygnusX1: Ah, I see what I did differently.  I used a const std::string, in which case VC++ does guarantee that you can access the '\0'.