# My program is executing as expected but in the end I am an extra line called a segmentation fault near the output. Could someone see to it?

Tags: c++, loops, segmentation-fault

Am not getting what is wrong with this

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{  // prints the initials of a name
    printf("Enter the name: ");
    string s = get_string(); 

    int n= 0;

    // prints the first letter of the name
    printf ("%c", toupper(s[0]));


    // rememnber the index of a string starts from 0 and it is counted till \0 and as \0 is the final one therefore it looks like it is counting from 1
    // but is actually starting at 0. The code accounts for that

    while(s[n] != '\0') // while we have not reached end of string
    {
        while(s[n] != ' ')
         {
            n = n +1 ;
         }

    printf("%c", toupper(s[n+1])); // prints the letter after the space in the uppercase order
    n = n+1;  // this sets the n at the letter just after the space

    }

   return 0;

}
```

input :

```
Rock Hilary
```

Expected output :

```
RH
```

What i am getting :

```
RHSegmentation fault
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing null-termination character in std::string (string subscript out of range)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299631/accessing-null-termination-character-in-stdstring-string-subscript-out-of-ran)

Comment: Here's how to fix this: there's a tool on your computer called a "debugger". Using this space-age technology allows you to execute your program, in the debugger, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables on each step. Using this amazing debugger it should be fairly easy for you to debug your program, and understand where its logic goes wrong. Good luck!

Comment: There's a smarter way to iterate over a `std::string`.

Comment: Think about what's happening in the inner loop if the last character isn't a space. (This is C, by the way, not C++. AFAIK, CS50 doesn't teach C++.)

Comment: @LogicStuff CS50 teaches C; this "string" is a typedeffed `char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged this as c++ but it seems like you're using entirely c.. So I'll answer this as if it's c.

A segmentation fault occurs when you access memory that you don't own. In this case you're trying to print a character outside of the bounds of your string. (e.g. your string is `len` characters long but you try to print character `len+1`).

In your case this is happening because of your inner while loop. Consider the string `abcd\0`.

For your outer while loop the case `s[n] != '\0'` succeeds because `s[n]` is `'a'`. We move then to your inner while loop. For all letters in your string `abcd\0` the case `s[n] != ' '` succeeds because none of the characters are a space. This means that your loop will continue to search for a byte that evaluates as a space character *past the end of your string*. Once you finally find one, *if* you finally find one you will try to print the character, which inevitably means that your program will segfault because it doesn't own the memory it's trying to access. If your program didn't segfault it would actually continue to do this, because your algorithm doesn't actually guarantee that you'll ever find a stopping point. The only time it would was if you had a character and then the end of the string (e.g. `a\0` or `abc d\0`).

You have some correct ideas, but to fix this you need to re-evaluate how you want your loop to execute. For the outer loop, you're using an incrementing variable to determine when to end your loop, consider changing this to a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
}
```

This is essentially the same as before, just cleaner. The real issue is your inside loop. Consider what you want to do here. You could do this with an inner loop, but you'd need to recheck the same outer condition. Let's try and find a solution that doesn't do that. Starting with we don't want to print spaces. This is a fairly simple addition:

```
for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    if (s[i] == ' ')
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Using continue will ensure that we'll restart the loop without running any of the rest of the code in the loop. We've also learend something interesting in this if: we've recently print a space. We can use this info if we track it so that we can print the next character (the initial). So let's add a boolean to watch for that.

```
int printedSpace = 0; // In c++ this would be `bool printedSpace = false;`
for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    if (s[i] == ' ')
    {
        printedSpace = 1; // In c++ this would be `printedSpace = true;`
        continue;
    }
}
```

Now that we know we're skipping space characters and that the next iteration we'll remember that we've printed a space we can use this info to print the character. Also, just to back-check our previous condition, that we'll stop at the end of the string (`'\0'`) we only read one character at a time, and then restart the loop (`continue`) so even if the last character in the string is `' '` (e.g. `"abcd    \0"`) we won't try to execute the loop again. Anyways, adding the print:

```
int printedSpace = 0; // In c++ this would be `bool printedSpace = false;`
for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    if (s[i] == ' ')
    {
        printedSpace = 1; // In c++ this would be `printedSpace = true;`
        continue;
    }
    else if (printedSpace)
    {
        printf("%c", toupper(s[i])); // Note that we're printing this character and not the next one
        printedSpace = 0; // In c++ this would be `printedSpace = false;`
    }
}
```

Two important things to notice here: first is that we reset `printedSpace` back to false so that we don't keep printing character, second is that if we have multiple spaces in a row it won't break anything, we'll just keep executing `continue` until we find a non-space character.  And frankly that's it. We've guaranteed that our count will stop at `'\0'` and we're printing characters after spaces. As a bonus, since you already assume that the first character in the string *is* an initial, if you set `printedSpace` to true before the beginning of the loop you will print the first character. This means you can remove the print above the loop. Just remember that you're assuming this, but I could break it by inputting `'     Rock Hilary'`. Of course you'll just print `' RH'`, since the rest of the algorithm will work as intended.

Comment: Remember you can accept answers. Good luck with learning c :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused becouse you are touching memory which doesnt belong to you (undefined behavior). Usually `SIGSEG` is thrown, same as in your case.

Problem occurs here

```
while(s[n] != ' ')
{
    n = n +1 ;
}
```

Where you are going behind `string` `null terminator`, just simply check if you reached `string` end, and if you did so, get out of loop.

```
while(s[n] != ' ' && s[n])
{
    n = n +1 ;
}
if (!s[n]) break;
```

Or a smarter way in C++, just an example

```
int main(void)
{
    std::string s = "Rock Hilary test";
    char prevChar = 0;

    if (s.length() < 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%c", toupper(s[0]));

    for(char c : s)
    {
        if (prevChar == ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(c));
        }
        prevChar = c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
RHT
```